# can't update MySQL table by PHP session

Tags: php, mysql, session

I can't update the MySQL table by value get from PHP session. I tested the valued got by PHP session is ok, and I also find there is the problem in `$sql_query1` in my code , but I can't fix it.

Here is the code:

**MySQL schema↓**

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `class` int(50) DEFAULT NULL ,
  `class_group` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `addr` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `seq` int(50) NOT NULL,
  `survey` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `survey_status` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `survey_date` date DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `test` (`class`, `class_group`, `name`, `addr`, `seq`, `survey`, `survey_status`, `survey_date`) VALUES
(1, 0, 'Michael　　', 'USA', 10, '', '', '0000-00-00'),
(1, 0, 'Jordan　　', 'CAN', 20, '', '', '0000-00-00');

ALTER TABLE `test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`seq`);
```

**index.php↓**

```
<?php
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

  <h2 align="center">Update_System</h2>

<form action="2_update.php" method="get">
  <fieldset>
  <legend><h2>System</h2></legend><br/>
  seq： <input type="text" name="seq"><br/>
  survey： <input type="text" name="survey"></br>
  survey_status： <input type="text" name="survey_status"><br/>
  survey_date： <input type="text" name="survey_date"><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<br>
<form action="1_test_preview.php" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="submit_preview" value="preview list">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**preview.php↓**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2 align="center">Result</h2>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit_preview'])){

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conn){die ("can not connect" . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("fs_change",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("set character set 'utf8'");

//set db connection
$sql_query1="select * from test";
$sql_nrow="select count(*) from test";
$result=mysql_query($sql_query1, $conn); 
$row_result=mysql_fetch_assoc($result); 
}
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1">
<table border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td>class</td>
<td>class_group</td>
<td>name</td>
<td>addr</td>
<td>seq</td>
<td>survey</td>
<td>survey_status</td>
<td>survey_date</td>
</tr>

<?php do { ?>

<tr>
<td><?php echo $row_result['class']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['class_group']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['name']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['addr']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['seq']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['survey']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['survey_status']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $row_result['survey_date']; ?></td>

<?php } while ($row_result = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));?>
<tr>

</table>
</form> 

<?php
mysql_free_result($result); 
?>
</body>
</html>
```

**update.php↓**

```
<?php
//get the data from session
session_start();
if(isset($_GET['seq'])){$_SESSION['seq']=$_GET['seq'];}
if(isset($_GET['survey'])){$_SESSION['survey']=$_GET['survey'];}
if(isset($_GET['survey_status'])){$_SESSION['survey_status']=$_GET['survey_status'];}
if(isset($_GET['survey_date'])){$_SESSION['survey_date']=$_GET['survey_date'];}



//set variables
    $seq = $_SESSION['seq'];
    $survey = $_SESSION['survey'];
    $survey_status = $_SESSION['survey_status'];
    $survey_date = $_SESSION['survey_date'];

//set db connection  
if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$conn=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$conn){die ("can not connect" . mysql_error());}
mysql_select_db("fs_change",$conn);
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
mysql_query("set character set 'utf8'");

//set sql query
$sql_query1="UPDATE fs SET survey = $survey, survey_status = $survey_status, survey_date = $survey_date WHERE seq = $seq";
mysql_query($sql_query1, $conn);
mysql_close($conn);
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    test sql_query1：
    <?php 
    if ($sql_query1 === TRUE) {
    echo 'Updated Successfully'
    ;}
    else {echo "Update Failed";}
    ?> <br>
    seq：<?php echo $seq?><br>
    survey：<?php echo $survey?><br>
    survey_state：<?php echo $survey_status?><br>
    survey_date：<?php echo $survey_date?><br>
    <input type = "button" name = "return" value = "back" onclick= "history.back()"> &nbsp;
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are just starting out with php mysql combo and you chose `mysql_` db extension. Why?

Comment: @Drew sorry, I can't understand what you mean?I'm a php + mysql beginner, could you tell me more?

Comment: `if ($sql_query1 === TRUE) {` wont be true as the variable holds the query and not the query execution result. Assign to a variable and then check in if condition as `$result = mysql_query($sql_query1, $conn);` then in the if condition `if ($result) {` will do the trick

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info and search on `PHP 5.5 and removed in PHP 7. Use PDO or MySqli instead.`

Comment: @Sasikumar : Thanks for your advise. I try it, still not work.

Comment: Also your missing the single quotes in the update query that had to be around each php variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the single quotes to the values. Use the below update SQL and HTML to get success or failure message.

```
$sql_query1="UPDATE fs SET survey = '$survey', survey_status = '$survey_status', survey_date = '$survey_date' WHERE seq = '$seq'";

$query_result = mysql_query($sql_query1, $conn);
mysql_close($conn);
} 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    test sql_query1：
    <?php 
    if ($query_result) {
    echo 'Updated Successfully'
    ;}
    else {echo "Update Failed";}
    ?> <br>
```

Comment: Thanks your advise, Now I got Update Successfully, but In MySQL database, it doesn't show the value which I just updated. How come?

Comment: You should check the data type and length of the table columns according to the maximum possibility of the insert / update value.

Comment: The schema of my database are as belows: 

seq: int(50)__this is primary key 
survey: varchar(50)
survey_status: varchar(50)
survey_date:varchar(50)

still don't work, why?

Comment: `echo $sql_query1="UPDATE fs SET survey = '$survey', survey_status = '$survey_status', survey_date = '$survey_date' WHERE seq = '$seq'"; exit;` - It will print the SQL statement. Copy that printed sql and run in phpmyadmin and see the output.

Comment: Thanks for your help, actually I finish my update process after adding quote on my variables. The reason why I can't show the right output is my typeo of my table name in **$sql_query1** variable. This help me a lot, Thanks.